# Understanding YeoJohnson transformation in R

Tags: r, data-preprocessing

I have tried to perform a YeoJohnson transformation using `caret` and `recipes`, but I think I am not specifying the calls properly or I am missing some extra parameters.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytuesdayR)

# Data is all numeric except for column 7
# get it from
# https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2023/2023-08-15/spam.csv
# or load it with tt_load()
spam <- tt_load(2023, week=33)$spam


# pre-process
pp_hpc <- caret::preProcess(spam[,1:6], 
                            method = c("center", "scale", "YeoJohnson"))
# fails to transform variables all variables
pp_hpc
Created from 4601 samples and 6 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (6)
  - ignored (0)
  - scaled (6)
  - Yeo-Johnson transformation (1)

Lambda estimates for Yeo-Johnson transformation:
0
```

```
# I can apply the transformation but obviously doesn't do the expected transformation in all the columns
transformed <- predict(pp_hpc, newdata = df$spam[,1:6])
```

Trying with `recipes` now

```
# recipes package 
library(recipes)
# do I really need this just to transform the data?
rec <- recipe(
  yesno ~ .,
  data = spam
)

yj_transform <- step_YeoJohnson(rec, all_numeric())
# only transform some variables
yj_estimates <- prep(yj_transform, verbose = T)
yj_estimates

── Recipe ────────────────────────────────────────────────

── Inputs 
Number of variables by role
outcome:   1
predictor: 6

── Training information 
Training data contained 4601 data points and no
incomplete rows.

── Operations 
• Yeo-Johnson transformation on: crl.tot, bang | Trained
```

Same, applying works, but not all columns are transformed (I am also not centering/scaling since it is not the problem here).

```
yj_te <- bake(yj_estimates, spam)
```

The `bestNormalize` package seems to have no issue here:

```
# works as expected
df_transformed <- select(spam, where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate_all(.funs = function(x) predict(bestNormalize::yeojohnson(x), newdata = x))
```

Just in case, this is how I would do it in python or using `reticulate`

```
# Python version
library(reticulate)
repl_python()
from sklearn import preprocessing
X = r.spam.drop('yesno', axis = 1)
scaler = preprocessing.PowerTransformer().set_output(transform="pandas")
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the Yeo-Johnson transformation requires a `lambda` value which either needs to be supplied or estimated. `step_YeoJohnson()` estimates a suitable value for each variable.

The `limits` argument sets a default range of values to search in. It defaults to `c(-5,5)`.

The documentation states:

> If the transformation parameters are estimated to be very closed to
> the bounds, or if the optimization fails, a value of NA is used and no
> transformation is applied.

So based on that, if you increase the bounds to search for suitable values of `lambda` in you'll likely see more variables being transformed. Indeed, when I run:

```
yj_transform <- step_YeoJohnson(rec, all_numeric(),limits = c(-20,20))
# only transform some variables
yj_estimates <- prep(yj_transform, verbose = T)
yj_estimates
```

The summary output reports that it ran the transformation on all 6 of the numeric variables, instead of just two, and running:

```
> tidy(yj_estimates,number = 1)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  terms        value id              
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>           
1 crl.tot   0.000979 YeoJohnson_jKN6C
2 dollar  -13.1      YeoJohnson_jKN6C
3 bang     -3.88     YeoJohnson_jKN6C
4 money   -14.6      YeoJohnson_jKN6C
5 n000    -13.4      YeoJohnson_jKN6C
6 make    -11.0      YeoJohnson_jKN6C
```

...reports that the estimated `lambda` values are well beyond the `(-5,5)` range for all but two of the variables.